# Automatically redirecting to another xaml page after 5 seconds

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing a Windows Phone 8.1 app. I want to know how to redirect to another xaml page after 5 seconds.
I want to perform the following thing:
When I click on a Log out button, it should navigate to another page(I can do this quite easily) but what I want is that page should not be displayed more than 5 seconds and it should navigate to some other specific page after 5 seconds.

Comment: Start the timer when you click the LogOut button. After 5 ticks do the navigation.

Comment: @LovetoCode actually I don't know to use Timer as I'm new to development. Can you please help?

Comment: Ok. I ll post the answer

Comment: @LovetoCode thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    //...

    private async void LogOut()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000); //wait for 5 seconds asynchronously 
        //TODO: perform navigate
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 DispatcherTimer timer;
        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (timer == null)
            {
                timer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) };
                timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
                timer.Start();
            }
        }
 private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));//Give your page here
        }
```

Comment: My bad, it didn't worked for me. I think the solution provided by RavingDev is pretty much simple and straight forward and it worked for me.

Comment: @AmanshuKataria I didn't add the code to start the timer. Updated my answer. This should work. I agree that other answer is simple. I posted this answer as another way of doing it. And it's not that complex also. You can choose whichever you want.